# JQUERY sortable won't call php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

So, I'm using Jquery to make 4 lists to be sortable between themselves, and up to the visual part, it works great, I can even receive their data-attributes, but I can't seem to call the PHP function on the RECEIVE event of the sortable lists.

I've tried a few times to call it differently, using other methods, but nothing seems to work.

```
<?php

require_once '../../DAO/model.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$week = $_POST['week'];

$query = "UPDATE onboarding_checklist_week 
SET week = '$week'
 WHERE id = 'id'";
mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($query));

 ?>
```

DAO/MODEL is my connection with SQL, it works just fine for the entire project, but as far as I can see, it's not even calling the PHP function, so it's not some connection problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#1').sortable({
    cancel: ".collapsible-header",
    connectWith: '#2, #3, #4, #5',
    receive: function (event,ui) {
        var id = ui.item.attr('data-identifier');
        var week = '1';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'changeEvents.ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'idTask' : id,
                'week': week
            }
        });
    }

});


$('#2').sortable({
    cancel: ".collapsible-header",
    connectWith: '#1, #3, #4, #5',
    receive: function (event,ui) {
        var id = ui.item.attr('data-identifier');
        var week = '2';
        $.ajax({
            url: "changeEvents.ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'idTask' : id,
                'week': week
            }
        });
        console.log('funcionou');
    }

});
```

It repeats three more times, one for each table.

It should be working, but it's not, doesn't matter how many times I move the elements around, it won't call my php function.

if I use console.log('id'), for example, I seem to be receiving the id of the elements just fine.

Comment: `WHERE id = 'id'"` is it typo?? why are u using file like `changeEvents.ajax.php` ?? and `$_POST['id'] != idTask`

Comment: Oh, yeah, I hadn't noticed, it's definitely a typo, but it's not even getting inside the php file at all, if I go and put echos in there, it won't echo anything, even before the function. 

Also, it was ChangeEvents.php, I think I saw this on a tutorial somewhere and tried it out, it didn't change anything anyway

Comment: Also PLEASE use a class and send the data-week - DRY, Don't repeat yourself

Comment: then u must need to post actual code

Comment: It is the actual code, I don't see what you mean.

Comment: its `ChangeEvents.php` or `changeEvents.ajax.php` or `changeEvents.php` ??? all of them different

Comment: as of the moment, it is changeEvents.ajax.php, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: i suggest you to use proper file name like `changeEventsajax.php`

Comment: not sure if it helps, but I was trying to follow this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPiq8Cvl5k4&t=335s tutorial

Comment: I tried changing the name to something like that, but it didn't affect and/or solve my problem at all, I think the problem must be somewhere else

Comment: in `changeEventsajax.php` file use just this code `echo Hello world`; at first line and remove all code, then open your browser console and check what r u getting in response.

Comment: well, I don't get anything.